# ArrayAdapter, ListView, creating and updating contents

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I posting this again, trying to make the question/problem clearer:

```
ListView lv;
List<Item> items;
Localstorage ls;
RemoteStorage rs;
ItemArrayAdapter adapter;

...

getShoppingList();  // <--- this method populates the items ArrayList
adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_listitem, 
                               items);  // <--- Create an ArrayAdapter and insert the 
                                        //      ArrayList...
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code so far populates the ArrayList items, creates an adapter and adds items to this, and then shows it in the ListView lv. So far, so good.

However, the getShoppingList() method is run several times, updating the ArrayList items. And instead of recreating the adapter every time this happens, I'd like to just update it and display the updated contents in the ListView lv.

What I'm trying is this:

OnClick method for the "Update" button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((Button)v).getText().equals("Update")) {
        try {
            tmpitems = rs.getNewEntries(cdate, latestitem);
            if (tmpitems.size() > 0) {
                updateFooter(tmpitems.size() + " new items found on server!");
                ls.UpdateLocalList(tmpitems);
                getShoppingList();               
                updateLatestItem(); 
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);    //
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     // THIS IS WHAT ISN'T WORKING
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);             //
            } else {
                updateFooter("No new items found on server.");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "NPException i onClick(): " + npe.toString());
            updateFooter("No new items found on server.");
        }
```

However, the lines for updating the adapter (after items have been updated) does absolutely nothing. I know that items is updated, because it's also written to a file, so the problem is not there. Besides, if I replace the lines for updating the adapter with lines for recreating it, it works nicely.

Update (sept. 16, 2012):

```
private void getShoppingList () {
    items = ls.getShoppingList(SHOPPINGLIST_FILE, cdate);
}
```

The ls.getShoppingList() method:

```
public List<Item> getShoppingList (String filename, String date) {
    String next[] = {};
    List<Item> nlist = new ArrayList<Item>();

    try {
        InputStream in = ctx.openFileInput("shoppinglists.csv");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr);

        for(;;) {
            next = reader.readNext();
            if(next != null) {
                if (next[0].equals(date)) {
                    nlist.add(new Item(next[0], next[1], next[2], 
                    next[3], next[4], next[5]));
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "IOException in List(): " + e.toString());
    }

    return nlist;
}
```

---------- Original post ------------------

I have a ListView lv with an ArrayAdapter for displaying rows of items.

```
List<Item> items;
ItemArrayAdapter adapter;
adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_listitem, 
                               items);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works nicely. The items arraylist is populated, and the adapter shows the contents in the ListView.

However, then I do some stuff that updates the ArrayList items. And then I want to update the adapter and the ListView. But this code,

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

obviously doesn't do it. So, how do I update the adapter and hence the ListView with the updated items ArrayList? Without reinitializing the adapter, that is?

EDIT:

The items ArrayList is updated thusly:

```
if (((Button)v).getText().equals("Update")) {
    try {
        tmpitems = rs.getNewEntries(cdate, latestitem);
            if (tmpitems.size() > 0) {
                ls.UpdateLocalList(tmpitems);
                getShoppingList();
                refreshList();
           } else {
           updateFooter("No new items found on server.");
       }
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "NPException i onClick(): " + npe.toString());
        updateFooter("No new items found on server.");
    }
}

refreshList() {
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

- New items are read into the tmpitems ArrayList.
- If the number of new items are >0, a local file is updated with the tmpitems.
- Then the items ArrayList is updated from the local file (with the getShoppingList() method, which adds the 
new entries)
- Then I try running the refreshList() method, which is supposed to update the adapter, as mentioened above.

The items ArrayList IS updated, and the local files are updated. It's just the update method on the adapter I can't get to work. When initializing the adapter, the items are shown in the ListView - when updating it, the new contents are not.

Comment: How do you update the items? Could you post some code?

Comment: try lv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: That line gives me this error: "The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((ItemArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Update:**
The thing is that `notifyDataSetChanged()` works only when the data *inside* the adapter has changed, and it rerenders the list. In your case you change the data *externally*, so you have to change the data *inside* the adapter.

You will need to replace `nlist.add(...)` with `insert()` and `remove()` methods of the adapter: [official reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29)

**Some clarification on how it works:** when you initialize adapter, it just sticks the items array you've passed to it to it's own ones. It is not aware of the changes made to your items array anymore.

Comment: That doesn't work - it gives the following error: "The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter"

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. The ListView is still empty until I restart the application, and the adapter is recreated.

Comment: then show us the code where you update the data in the adapter.

Comment: In the public void onClick (View v) method above. I just replaced the line "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" with "((ItemArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()";

Comment: I mean these methods: getShoppingList();               
                updateLatestItem();

Comment: I've pasted the getShoppingList() method. The updateLatestItem() only updates an int containing the ID of the latest Item item, so that has absolutely nothing to do with the adapter. It's just for passing and ID to the php script accessing the DB.

Comment: Ok, so I need to use insert/add/remove methods and manually insert or remove each line? That will require more code, and I'm starting to doubt whether it will be any better than just recreating it... Then again, it might.

Comment: Yes, that's what you need. Whether it is better to recreate the adapter depends on how much items and how often are changed.

Comment: Hm. I'm testing this a bit, and at the moment I'm doing this: 1. On app startup, create the array with this line: adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_listitem, items); Then, on update, I just run this line for every new item: adapter.add(tmpitems.get(i)); ----- Now, this immediately updates the view, without needting to run notifyDataSetChanged(). However, it does of course put the latest items at the bottom of the view, instead of the top, but I guess that's easy to rearrange.

Comment: Pragmatic conclusion: I've landed on this: When updating, simply clear the adapter and then re-read the updated items<Item> into it again. Then the view is automatically updated, and there doesn't seem to be a need for calling notifyDataSetChanged() in this context.